# Java Graphics2D, JPanel, JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, graphics2d

I'm working right now on a project, and I can't find a solution for my problem.

So here is my problem: I have a JFrame, then I add a container JPanel, and I add 2 other JPanel to this container panel , first panel (InputPanel) is for user input, second panel (Board) for displaying the specified algorithm based on the user input.

But the displayed algorithm is too large, so I thought I will add a JScrollPane to the DisplayPanel, but it didn't worked like I thought it would have. Here is a picture, the red rectangle is the area what changed after I added the JScollPane: [image]

Notice that at my Board class I override the paintComponent(Graphics g) to draw the algorithm.

My code in the main frame:

```
    container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    board = new Board();
    container.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    inputPanel = new InputPanel(board);
    container.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pane = new JScrollPane(board);
    pane.setViewportView(board);
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 0));
    container.add(pane, BorderLayout.WEST);

    add(container);
```

My initial plan was to add a horizontal scrollpane to the Board panel. Can somebody post an example code, or point out for my problem pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the board twice to container. Add the JScrollPane to the center of container, and continue to pass board to the constructor of your JScrollPane. Don't add the board individually to the container if you want to add it via a JScrollPane.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem partly. I also forgot to set the preferredsize of the board, so the scollpane didn't worked firstly, but now its good. Thank you :)